# Open multiple Eclipse workspaces on the Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos

How can I open multiple Eclipse workspaces at the same time on the Mac?

On other platforms, I can just launch extra Eclipse instances, but the Mac will not let me open the same application twice. Is there a better way than keeping two copies of Eclipse?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

**EDIT:** [Milhous's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/386470/16562) seems to be the officially supported way to do this as of 10.5. Earlier version of OS X and even 10.5 and up should still work using the following instructions though.

---

1. Open the **command line** (Terminal)
2. Navigate to your Eclipse installation folder, for instance:

   - `cd /Applications/eclipse/`
   - `cd /Developer/Eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`
   - `cd /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`
   - `cd /Users/<usernamehere>/eclipse/jee-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS`
3. Launch Eclipse: `./eclipse &`

This last command will launch eclipse and immediately background the process.

Rinse and repeat to open as many unique instances of Eclipse as you want.

---

#### Warning

You might have to **change the Tomcat** server ports in order to run your project in **different/multiple Tomcat instances**, see [Tomcat Server Error - Port 8080 already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34259707/759452)

Comment: true, but the OP mentions Mac.

Comment: The answer is missing some parts of the path.  For example, mine is: /Developer/Eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse &

Comment: Worked as written for me. No need to delve deeper into the application package. (Although it did give me the error that my workspace was already open.)

Comment: But now I can't close the terminal window until I close eclipse

Comment: @LaraDougan why is your Eclipse located under /Developer?

Comment: Here is another way to do that and it will not background the process as well..Here is the link: https://blogs.oracle.com/dns/entry/opening_multiple_eclipse_instances_on

Comment: For the mac, you can make an alias to do this from any directory in the terminal as well: alias eclipse='open -n /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app'. The -n is for "Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running."

Comment: For some reason I can't fathom, after months of working fine, today this solution is no longer working for me, so I switched to Milhous' solution.

Comment: For eclipse mars : `./Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`

Comment: While the solution here works for me, unfortunately it loses all of my BetterTouchTool shortcuts for Eclipse for the second copy.  Perhaps a different path/executable would work better with BetterTouchTool.

Comment: For me path was : /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: this still works on 10.14 but I think the 'open -n Eclipse.app' is a cleaner approach

Answer (score 244):

This seems to be the supported native method in OS X:

```
cd /Applications/eclipse/

open -n Eclipse.app
```

Be sure to specify the ".app" version (directory); in OS X Mountain Lion erroneously using the symbolic link such as `open -n eclipse`, might get one GateKeeper stopping access:

> "eclipse" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.
>
> Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the Mac App Store and identified developers.

Even removing the extended attribute `com.apple.quarantine` does not fix that. Instead, simply using the ".app" version will rely on your previous consent, or prompt you once:

> "Eclipse" is an application downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?

Comment: It worked for me too... Working completely fine. Thanks A lot

Comment: Brilliant - definitely a +1 for this help.  It really shouldn't be this hard...you're a lifesaver.

Comment: This is the better answer IMHO because Eclipse still stays running (even if you close Terminal

Comment: for Eclipse Mars: `./Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer:
`-n  Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running.`

Comment: (Now in /Applications/Eclipse Java.app/Contents/MacOS)

Answer (score 182):

By far the best solution is the OSX Eclipse Launcher presented in http://torkild.resheim.no/2012/08/opening-multiple-eclipse-instances-on.html It can be downloaded in the Marketplace http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/osx-eclipse-launcher#.UGWfRRjCaHk

I use it everyday and like it very much! To demonstrate the simplicity of usage just take a look at the following image:

[image: Image demonstrating the plugin usage: Just go File / Open Workspace / select one]

Comment: Nice. It even adds a nice badge to the Dock icon(s), and to the icons in the task switcher. Perfect!

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution to implement and best addresses the spirit of the question. The other answers seem to be scored higher based on their age alone.

Comment: This is easily the way to go.  If you always start multiple instances you could script that into the CLI.  But if it's just on occasion you start another instance, this is the way to go.

Comment: Nice! Even if the `Launch New Workspace` isn't visible in Eclipse `ADT` (Android Developer Tools), but it opens a second workspace if you choose `Open Workspace`

Comment: A really nice feature to Eclipse! I only have "Open Workspace" option in the menu after installed the plugin but it is possible to create a new workspace by choosing "Other..." anyway.
I wonder if there is any similar plugin to Windows version...?

Comment: Was really excited by this, but it didn't work for me.  Trying to install and getting the following error in Luna:
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
no.resheim.eclipse.utils.launcher.feature.group [2.0.0.201411211032] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.

Comment: @kfox This is typically an indicator of a platform/ui/arch mismatch. What are you running?

Comment: @torkildr I'm running Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600 OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

Comment: Here is the error that's displayed: Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  no.resheim.eclipse.utils.launcher.feature.group [2.0.0.201411211032] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.

Comment: I suspect you're not running Eclipse on Java 7 or better.

Comment: This is a nice plugin

Comment: Here's the current link to the updated plugin: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/os-x-eclipse-launcher ..especially relevant because searching on Eclipse's marketplace website right now leads to an infinite redirect... (sigh)

Comment: Great plugin! Any idea why the dock badge does not stay? I see it for just a second when I launch new eclipse instance, but then it disappears.

Comment: This works like a charm. There are some old comments on market place which says it didnt work, but looks like after recent update all good. Tried with latest java 8 update, latest mac high sierra (10.13.4), Eclipse latest Oxygen 3.a
PS: Ya Mac window management is amazing, you need a separate utility just to open two instances of same app. :(

Comment: Freakin' awesome! I was just thinking it would be great to add the badge with the workspace (I use 4 at once at the moment). I have also just implemented this myself for my java mac desktop application. I googled and hey presto! Like magic. :) "Open Workspace" menu might even be considered as a standard eclipse menu.

Comment: WIsh I could have given multiple +++ for this :) Thank you!!

Answer (score 26):

To make this you need to navigate to the Eclipse.app directory and use the following command:

```
open -n Eclipse.app
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, its the best option, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

Actually a much better (GUI) solution is to copy the Eclipse.app to e.g. Eclipse2.app and you'll have two Eclipse icons in Dock as well as Eclipse2 in Spotlight. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: This is what I actually ended up doing. In fact, since I rarely upgrade Eclipse during ongoing projects, but start new projects with the latest Eclipse, I now have three different versions of Eclipse, all in the dock.

Comment: I do much the same, but I have an app copy per workspace, and then add this to Info.plist: <string>-data</string><string>pathto/workspaces/myworkspace</string>. That plus a plugin to add icon badges based on workspace name, and I'm a happy camper.

Answer (score 19):

If the question is how to easily use Eclipse with multiple *different* workspaces, then you have to use a kludge because shortcuts in OS X do not provide a mechanism for passing command line arguments, for example the "--data" argument that Eclipse takes to specify the workspace.  While there may be different reasons to create a duplicate copy of your Eclipse install, doing it for this purpose is, IMNSHO, lame (now you have to maintain multiple eclipse configurations, plugins, etc?).

In any case, here is a workaround.  Create the following script in the (single) Eclipse directory (the directory that contains Eclipse.app), and give it a ".command" suffix (e.g. eclipse-workspace2.command) so that you can create an alias from it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# open, as suggested by Milhous
open -n $(dirname $0)/Eclipse.app --args -data /path/to/your/other/workspace
```

Now create an alias to that file on your desktop or wherever you want it.
You will probably have to repeat this process for each different workspace, but at least it will use the same Eclipse installation.

Comment: +1 for the workaround solution, and I want to put in an argument for having multiple workspaces with different settings.  As a contractor, you often have to adopt the client's styles and preferences.  By creating a new workspace you can easily partition your work among several clients.  Also, you may have to support an old account while working on a new account.  With this scheme you can keep both open at the same time.  I currently keep switching between workspaces, but I like this convenience of opening both (all) at once as needed.

Answer (score 6):

## 2018 Update since many answers are no longer valid

## OS X Heigh Sierra (10.13) with Eclipse Oxygen

Go to wherever your Eclipse is installed. Right-click -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> MacOS -> Double-click the executable called eclipse

A terminal window will open and a new instance of eclipse will start.

**Note that if you close the terminal window, the new Eclipse instance will be closed also.**

[image]

To make your life easier, you can drag the executable to your dock for easy access

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of copying Eclipse.app around, create an automator that runs the shell script above.

Run automator, create Application.

choose Utilities->Run shell script, and add in the above script (need full path to eclipse)

Then you can drag this to your Dock as a normal app.

Repeat for other workspaces.

You can even simply change the icon - https://discussions.apple.com/message/699288?messageID=699288򪮘

Answer (score 4):

One another way is just to duplicate only the "Eclipse.app" file instead of making multiple copies of entire eclipse directory. Right-Click on the "Eclipse.app" file and click the duplicate option to create a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Launch terminal and run `open -n /Applications/Eclipse.app` for a new instance.

Answer (score 3):

Lets try downloading this in your eclipse on Mac you will be able to open multiple eclipse at a time [Link](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/osx-eclipse-launcher#.UGWfRRjCaHk)

Name : macOS Eclipse Launcher

Steps :

1. Go to eclipse Market place.
2. Search for "macOS Eclipse Launcher" and install.
3. It will restart .
4. Now under file menu check for open option > there you will find other projects to open also at same time .

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me, you probably have terminal running most of the time as well. 
You could just create an alias in /Users//.bash_profile like this
alias eclipse='open -n path_to_eclipse.app'

then all you have to do is just open the terminal and type eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a previous answer that helped me, but different directory:

```
cd /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS
./eclipse &
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create an AppleScript file to open Eclipse with a given workspace. You can even save the AppleScript file as an Application, which is equivalent to creating an alias with arguments in Windows OS.

Open Script Editor and type the following:

```
do shell script "open '/path/to/your/Eclipse/installation' -n --args -data /path/to/your/workspace"
```

For instance:

```
do shell script "open '/Applications/Eclipse.app' -n --args -data /MyWorkspaces/Personal"
```

Press the Run button to check it's working.

This script can be saved as such, but I prefer to save it as an Application. That way I can customize the icon by copying the *.icns icon from the original Eclipse.app bundle to the script application bundle.

To open an App folder, use the "see contents" contextual menu option. It should look like this:

[image: contents of script app]

Where "main.scpt" is the AppleScript file and "applet.icns" is the icon from the original Eclipse bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution a while back, can't remember where but it still seems to work well for me.

Create a copy of Eclipse.app for each workspace you want to work in (for this example ProjectB.app), then open ProjectB.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini and add these two lines at the beginning of the file:

```
-data
/Users/eric/Workspaces/projectb
```

... substituting where your workspace is located. When you launch ProjectB.app it will automatically start with that workspace instead of prompting for a location, and you should be able to run it at the same time as other Eclipse instances with no problem.

Comment: its really waste of disk space copying whole eclipse app

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open multiple workspaces and you are **not** a **terminal** guy, just locate the Unix executable file in your eclipse folder and click it.

The path to the said file is

> Eclipse(folder) -> eclipse(right click) -> Show package
>   Contents -> Contents -> MacOs -> eclipse(unix executable file)

Clicking on this executable will open a separate instance of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal simply paste below line and hit enter ..

/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse ; exit;

Answer (score 0):

A more convenient way:

1. Create an executable script as mentioned above:

   #!/bin/sh

   cd /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6

   open -n Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6.app
2. In you current instance of Flashbuilder or Eclipse, add a new external tool configuration.  This is the button next to the debug/run/profile buttons on your toolbar.  In that dialog, click on "Program" and add a new one.  Give it the name you want and in the "Location" field, put the path to the script from step 1:

   /Users/username/bin/flashbuilder
3. You can stop at step 2, but I prefer adding a custom icon to the toolbar.  I use a the Quick Launch plugin to do that:

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/quicklaunch/files/
4. After adding the plugin, go to "Run"->"Organize Quick Lauches" and add the external tool config from step 2.  Then you can configure the icon for it.
5. After you save that, you'll see the icon in your toolbar.  Now you can just click it every time you want a new Flashbuilder/Eclipse instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple instances of Eclipse by creating a pseudonym for Eclipse application in it's folder and using it for running new Eclipse instance

Answer (score -8):

```
Window -> New Window
```

This opens a new window and you can then open another project in it. You can use this as a workaround hopefully.

It actually allows you to work in same workspace.