# Workspace dialog is not coming

Tags: eclipse

When I'm launching my eclipse application, the workspace selection dialog box is not coming. When I checked the settings in preference pages, the check box was selected for "Prompt for workspace on startup". Has anybody come across this situation?

Comment: May be you have selected "Use this as default and do not ask again." on that dialog and now it is set as default and you can not see prompt.

Comment: It *should* show up, when the property is set. Please have a look at the eclipse error logs, there may be a problem with a plugin/bundle.

Comment: @Harry Joy - but that should clear the checkbox in the preference page - and that one is still selected..

Comment: @Harry Joy- I didn't select "Use this as default and do not ask again." @Andreas_D- I am not getting any error in plugin/bundle for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use another workspace than the default - or what have become the default - you can specify the `-data <path>` argument at start-up in the shortcut. I usually have a shortcut for each of my important workspaces - for the current set of active customers - and have linked these to my desktop.

Having said that, I don't know why you have the problem you have. The `Prompt for workspace at startup` setting usually works fine for me...

Comment: It depends on the operating system. For Windows, you right-click Eclipse and choose "Create shortcut". This shortcut can then be edited using "Properties" and you can add `-data <path>`. For OSX, you create a `.command` file with the content `exec open -n .../Eclipse.app --args -data <path>` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118243/open-multiple-eclipse-workspaces-on-the-mac/2390324#2390324 For Linux and other Unix-based platforms you can create a `.sh` file with with the content `exec .../eclipse -data <path> &`. `...` is the full path to the Eclipse executable...

Comment: After long time I found the problem. Actually problem was from some other plugin which was suppressing the workspace dialog box. Once i removed those plugins, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i think i know what you're talking about, i had this problem once, when i checked the box the problem got resolved, i would try unchecking the box, then closing eclipse, then open it up again and check the box and close it again, then see if the problem persists, if it does i have a way around it, if you want to switch to a different workspace then you can go to file-> switch workspace -> and then a recent workspace or select other to manually select a directory.

Hope that helped!

- John

Comment: @ John Detter- Sorry it didn't help. I already know the other way around you suggested.

Comment: Ok, if its really that bothersome then you could just re-install it, im sure that would fix it

Comment: After long time I found the problem. Actually problem was from some other plugin which was suppressing the workspace dialog box. Once i removed those plugins, it worked fine.

Comment: oh well im glad u found the solution to your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

start eclipse using eclipse -clean

It will work.
Thanks to some comment on the eclipse issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=134412

Comment: Your solution might be helpful in some cases, but please consider that the OP has already found the problem: it was an external plugin. He explained it in the comments of other answers.