# How to open multiple Spring STS instances on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos

Any time I double click the STS icon it opens the same instance again.

How can I open multiple instances?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118243/open-multiple-eclipse-workspaces-on-the-mac)

So

Go to eclipse install directory and run following from command line:

```
./STS &
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to use open command with -n parameter

```
 1. Open terminal
 2. cd /Applications/
 3. open -n STS.app/
```

The same command can be used to open 2 eclipse instances. But 3rd command should be 
open -n Eclipse.app/

With this command, we can open as many instances as we want.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You must use different workspace. It is the same for windows as well. Opening the same workspace doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 9):

Also check out the open command which can be used from the command line. In particular, open -n any.app will open a new instance of the application even if one is already running. This will work with any application, not just STS or eclipse where a convenient shell script is provided for you.

Comment: +1 for going above and beyond original question! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the steps that worked for me

1. Go to STS folder
2. right click on STS file and select Show Package Content
3. Goto Content->MacOS
4. Right click on STS and select Make Alias

Once above steps are done. Copy the alias somewhere at the sts level and click on it to start another instance of sts.

Comment: Only this worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to type in the terminal:

$`open -n /Applications/STS.app`

If you prefer just to write a word, maybe you need an alias, type:

$`nano .bash_profile` or `nano .zsh`

and add the next line:

```
alias spring="open -n /Applications/STS.app"
```

close and save, the just type:

$`source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.zsh`

close terminal, open and type:

$`spring`