# Eclipse Kepler Error on Startup Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos

When Running Eclipse Kepler on mac os x 10.9.3 I get a red error bubble on the top of the eclipse icon in the dock.  It is a horizontally shaped oval with the contents being **wor..nch**  I assume it is this truncated error is saying "workspace [some error] [my workspace name]" because my workspace name ends in "nch". 
Eclipse runs okay, but I would like to know what the error is and clear it.  How can I clear this error?

Comment: The red item in the dock is a 'badge' and it may not be an error - they can be used by the notification system or the app itself. However I have not seen Eclipse do this.

Comment: Is there a way to read the full message?  Where does it live?

Comment: You could look in the Notification Center to see if that is showing a message, otherwise I don't know.

Comment: I found out what it is.  I installed the 'open multiple workspaces' plugin for Eclipse on the Mac.  As one of the comments points out it shows the work space location as the badge. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118243/open-multiple-eclipse-workspaces-on-the-mac