# How to make port 8080 free for Tomcat in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: java, netbeans, web-deployment, tomcat9

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 along with JDK-8.
I have installed Tomcat9 for making Web Application in net-beans but when ever i start tomcat9 it shows port 8080 is busy.
I ran following command

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```

and killed the process using

```
# kill -9 <process_id>
```

but after that when I start tomcat9 it shows **the server port 8080 is already in use.** and I again killed the process but another process **again starts on port 8080 immediately** and I can't start the Tomcat9.

I tried by changing port number but still error is same.

Can anyone tell me where's problem occurring and what should i do now?

Comment: can u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253779/tomcat-server-error-port-8080-already-in-use

Comment: Which process starts on 8080?

Comment: @DusanBajic when I run `sudo lsof -i :8080`, every time it shows that this process is running by Command **JAVA** with some **PROCESS_ID** by User **TOMCAT**.

Comment: Workaround: Change the config file in Tomcat to listen on another port.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a service configured to be restarted if it crashes.

Figure out what sits on the port and disable the service or remove the package completely.