# Port 8080 is already in use

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services

The method works properly without path variable but then when I write path variable and run app it says port 8080 is already in use

```
@GetMapping(path="/{userId}")
public String getUser(@PathVariable String userId) {
    return "Get User Info with id "+userId;
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the @PathVariable. This says that you already have a process running on the same port. My guess is that you try running a new one and the old one is still running

Comment: What is the operation system? depends your OS, you need to understand which app holds this port, if it a different app from your app you can change the 8080 in springboot application.properties [server.port=XXXX]. In case your springboot app already holds it you should kill the process from IDE or command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253779/tomcat-server-error-port-8080-already-in-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, on Windows

```
netstat ano | findstr 8080 

taskkill /F /PID <number of task>
```

Answer (score 4):

First your issue is not with **Path variable**, Port **8080** is been used by some **other application**

Command for Linux,

```
sudo netstat -nlap | grep 8080
sudo kill <process id>
```

Command for Windows

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8080
taskkill /PID <process id> /F
```

If any application uses the port 8080, it will return the process id.

Answer (score 3):

On mac, try this

```
sudo lsof -i :8080

# get the process id from here and run

kill -9 <process_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid from Port was already in use just put server.port=0 in yml or properties file ,it will auto generate port number for application.