# Allocate exception for servlet in Java

Tags: java

I am a newbie in Java Server Programming. I'm struggling with a problem when running the project.
When I first ran the project, I got the same error with this problem: [Tomcat Server Error - Port 8080 already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253779/tomcat-server-error-port-8080-already-in-use).

But when I changed the port, it became like this:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [HS]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: webapp.HelloServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://JAVA.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
    <display-name>Example_11</display-name>
    <description>

        Servlet Demos.
    </description>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>webapp.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/helloServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My java file

```
package webapp;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><head>");
        out.println("<title>Hello Servlet</title>");
        out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css' />");
        out.println("</head><body>");
        out.print("<p>Today is: " + new Date());
        out.print("</p>");
        out.print("<h1>The Hello Servlet Demo</h1>");
        out.println("<p>This is the first hello servlet</p>");
        out.println("<img src='images/Tulips.PNG' width='100' height='100' />");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

[image]

I am new to this subject. Can someone explain why do those errors happen? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClassNotFoundException: webapp.HelloServlet
```

This means that Tomcat cannot find file `HelloServlet.class`. This is the file that is created when you compile your java source code.

Servlet classes, such as your `HelloServlet` class, must be placed in a directory named `classes` below the `WEB-INF` directory.

Since your servlet is in a package name `webapp`, you need to create a `webapp` directory below the `classes` directory.

Then copy file `HelloServlet.class` to directory `WEB-INF/classes/webapp`.

Refer to [Java EE Tutorials](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jee-tutorials.html)

Comment: So I have to create a classes directory even when I use an IDE like I'm using Eclipse?

Comment: @HowardDuong are you using [Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-06/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers)? I don't use it so I don't know but I assume it helps you to create Web applications that contain servlets.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it.