# Tomcat does allow me access with the user that I registered

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, xampp

[image: AuthenticationRequired]

I have a problem: when starting Tomcat I put the same credentials in the **Authentication Required** screen that I created in **tomcat-users.xml**, but this does not work for me.

Here is the content of **tomcat-users.xml**:

[image: tomcat-users.xml]

I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: The error message in your screenshot is `Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use.` Is that the problem you _actually_ need to resolve? If so, see [Tomcat Server Error - Port 8080 already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34253779/12567365) and many similar questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You should also take a look at [why you should not upload images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question. The [ask] page also provides additional background guidance. Welcome!

Comment: Your question is presented [as an XY problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341): you want to resolve the problem of not being able to authenticate, but your actual problem, as @andrewJames pointed out, is _"Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use"_. So the most likely solution is to ensure that Tomcat is not already running before you start it, but regardless you need to ensure that port 8080 is available. Alternatively, use a different port number. If you do that then your perceived problem - authentication failing - will probably resolve itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deployment error:Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310945/deployment-errorstarting-of-tomcat-failed-the-server-port-8080-is-already-in-u)