# Spring Boot App deployed on Azure App Service port 8080

Tags: linux, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot Rest Api (Gradle) to an Azure app service. There is an executable jar in the /home/site/wwwroot folder and a startup command (java -jar /home/site/wwwroot/app.jar). When I execute this script, the spring api starts but throws the following error: "The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured."

I can't run the app on another port because the Azure App Service only allows inbound HTTP traffic on port 80 and 443 for SSL. I tried killing the process that is running on port 80 but that kills my ssh terminal.

Is there a solution to 'clear' the proces running on port 80 and actually run my Spring application on it?

Answer (score 0):

> "The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start.The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured."

The error is because another process is running on the same port. To solve this, you have two options.

1. Try to run the application on a port other than 8080.
2. Identify and stop the process running on that specific port.

Check this post on [how to change the default tomcat port number](https://springhow.com/change-default-port-number-in-spring-boot/).
See: [how the spring boot configuration works](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).

Check this [blog](https://springhow.com/web-server-failed-to-start-port-8080-was-already-in-use/) and SO thread might be helpful. [Tomcat Server Error - Port 8080 already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253779/tomcat-server-error-port-8080-already-in-use)