# Open (maven, gradle) project in Eclipse from command line (bash on macOS/Linux)

Tags: bash, eclipse, maven, gradle, command-line

As of 2023, it is trivial to open project in IDEA or VS Code from command line

E.g. on MacOS just add this to your `.bashprofile`/`.zprofile`

```bash
# Run ms VSCode from terminal
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065227/run-open-vscode-from-mac-terminal
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}

#open /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/
# https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#c668f7d8
idea () { open -n /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/ --args $* ;}
```

The just `idea .` to open current folder project in IDEA

**Question: How to open Eclipse from command line?**

I can narrow down to just maven/gradle project using bash (on macOS/Linux)

Comment: `open -n -a Eclipse` opens Eclipse. There isn't an argument for a single project `-data /path/to/workspace` opens a workspace.

Comment: Welcome to 2023, it's `eclipse .` (assuming your Eclipse is up to date).

Comment: @greg-449 `eclipse <file>` starts Eclipse, if not yet running, and opens the file and `eclipse <dir>` opens the smart import dialog for the directory (_File > Open Projects from File System..._).

Comment: @howlger Note that you can't just type "eclipse" in a mac terminal / script, it is necessary to use `open` because Eclipse is a mac app not a unix executable.

Comment: @greg-449 But it should be possible via `.bashprofile` to create an alias `eclipse` that passes e.g. the current directory (`.`) as argument to the Eclipse app, right? `eclipse () { open -n -a Eclipse --args $* ;}`?

Comment: @howlger Sure (it is actually .zprofile these days as macOS defaults to zsh now).

Comment: @greg-449 Please add an answer with the exact line for `.zprofile` and/or `.bashprofile`.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS applications are typically launched via the [`open` command](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/02/the-macos-open-command/).

But the `open` command does not support passing arguments to the application being opened.
However, you can use the `open` command with the `-a` option to open an application, and you can specify the application name instead of the path:

```bash
open -a Eclipse
```

This will *not* open a specific project directly, since Eclipse does not natively support opening specific projects via command line.

---

An alternative is to create an AppleScript that starts Eclipse and then uses the UI scripting capabilities of AppleScript to [navigate the menus to open a project](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/PromptforaFileorFolder.html). You can see an example in "[Open multiple Eclipse workspaces on the Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50321398/6309)"

It is better to use a shell script as a wrapper around the AppleScript, since AppleScript itself does not support command line arguments.

For instance:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if a parameter was given
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    # No parameter given, ask for workspace
    osascript -e '
    -- Ask for a new workspace path
    set newWorkspace to choose folder with prompt "Select your workspace folder:"
    
    -- Open the selected workspace
    do shell script "open /Applications/Eclipse.app -n --args -data " & POSIX path of newWorkspace'
else
    # Parameter given, use as workspace
    workspace="$1"

    # If the parameter is a dot, expand to current working directory
    if [[ "$workspace" == "." ]] ; then
        workspace="$PWD"
    fi

    # Open the workspace
    osascript -e "do shell script \"open /Applications/Eclipse.app -n --args -data $workspace\""
fi
```

You can save this script in a file, for example `eclipse_workspace.sh`. Make sure to make it executable by running `chmod +x eclipse_workspace.sh`.

You can then call this script from the command line with or without a parameter:

- With a parameter: `./eclipse_workspace.sh /path/to/workspace`
- With a dot as a parameter: `./eclipse_workspace.sh .`
- Without a parameter: `./eclipse_workspace.sh`

Result:

- In the first case, it will use the given path as the workspace.
- In the second case, it will use the current working directory as the workspace.
- In the third case, it will ask you to select a workspace.

You can then define an alias to `eclipse_workspace.sh` (I like `alias e=/path/to/eclipse_workspace.sh`).
And then, from command-line, you would type...

```
e
```

Or

```
e .
```

Or

```
e /path/to/workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all open your `.bashprofile` file using a text editor

```
vi ~/.bashprofile
```

then add this to your`.bashprofile` file

```
eclipse () { open -n /Applications/Eclipse.app/ --args $* ;}
```

now save the changes, exit the file, and enter this line:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

from now on, you can easily open `Eclipse` like the line below:

```
eclipse .
```

good luck !

Comment: The question was How to open project in Eclipse from command line (not how to edit or content of `.bashprofile`).
`open -n /Applications/Eclipse.app/ .` did not worked for me:
> The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x12b614cd0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=162 "Unknown error: 162" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}

Awarding bounty anyways, as it was the only answer.

Answer (score 0):

This function works both in Macos and Linux :

```
eclipse(){
    local -a cmd data
    test -v 1 && data=(-data "$(builtin cd "$1"; pwd)")
    [[ "${OSTYPE-}" = darwin* ]] &&
        cmd=(open /Applications/Eclipse.app --args) ||
        cmd=(command eclipse)
    "${cmd[@]}" "${data[@]}"
}
```

it allows to start in default workspace with

```
eclipse
```

start with current directory as workspace

```
eclipse .
```

start with a particular directory as workspace

```
eclipse ../eclipse-workspace2
```